# Logistic Regression using Gradient Descent

Tags: machine-learning, regression, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

The given data on student exam results and our goal is to predict whether a student will
pass or fail based on number of hours slept and hours spent studying. We have two features (hours
slept, hours studied) and two classes: passed (1) and failed (0).

```
Studied Slept Passed
4.85    9.63  1
8.62    3.23  0
5.43    8.23  1
9.21    6.34  0
```

Can anyone please explain how to calculate the first two iterations of cost??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say one iteration of your training accepts one sample from your dataset. Since you are using logistic regression, your initial prediction is going to be

```
p = sigmoid(x1*w1 + x2*w2 + b)
```

where `x1` and `x2` are the studied and slept input values. `w1` and `w2` are the weights of your model, and `b` is the bias vector. This will return a value between 0 and 1.

Also note that I have named the value on the left `p`, since this is the models predicted value.

The **cost** for this iteration, if you're using binary cross entropy, is going to be:

```
−(y*log(p) + (1−y)*log(1−p))
```

where y is the true value of the input sample. If we take the first input sample in your training data, the true value is `1`.

Therefore, your **cost**, `J`, is:

```
J = -(1*log(p) + (1-1)*log(1-p))
  = -log(p)
```

Since we now know the value of the **cost**, which is a function of the parameters of the model, we can use the chain rule to find the gradient of the parameters with respect to the **cost** (or error).

You would then update the parameters of the model with the following equations:

```
wn = wn - alpha * dJ/dwn
b  = b  - alpha * dJ/db
```

where `n = 1, 2` and `alpha` is the learning rate of your model.

For the next iteration, you would just do the same process with another sample from your dataset.